# laravel carbon unset date

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Right now I have a model that has a "followup" date that is rotected to convert to carbon (). The issue is in my controller if I have some dates that are not set and default (`0000-00-00`) Carbon returns them as `-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000`. I get why, but trying to target those dates and just return "none" but cant figure out how.

in my controller:

```
foreach ($account->notes as $note) {

                $notes[$i]['note']       = $note;
                $notes[$i]['account']    = $account->name;

                if($note->followup != '-0001-11-30 00:00:00.000000'){
                     $notes[$i]['followup']   = $note->followup->diffForHumans();
                 } else {
                    $notes[$i]['followup']   = 'None';
                 }


               $i += 1;
           }
```

Comment: Where is your default date `0000-00-00` coming from? If it's your database, update your schema to set default to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach should give you the output you're looking for:

```
foreach ($account->notes as $note) {
    $notes[$i]['note']     = $note;
    $notes[$i]['account']  = $account->name;
    $notes[$i]['followup'] = (substr($note->followup, 0, 1) !== '-') ? $note->followup->diffForHumans() : 'None';

    $i += 1;
}
```

But I'm confused as to why the approach you posted isn't working if you're checking for the precise value you're dumping out in your conditional statement.